# Counting up a column incorrectly SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I am having a problem working out why a query I am writing is counting up the overall views for a page and not for each organisation, it should come out as 19 and 8 but when I run the query it comes out as 27 page view each the rest of the query seems to work fine. anyone got an idea why? Thanks
Thomas

```
SELECT orgID, orgName, 
    (SELECT COUNT (rvSessionKey)
    FROM tblReport
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblReportView  ON rptID = rv_rptID
    WHERE rpt_orgID IN (1002,1047)  
            AND rvEmail NOT LIKE '%support%' 
            AND rpt_qtrID IN (1)) AS [Page View],
    COUNT( DISTINCT rvSessionKey ) AS [Views], COUNT(DISTINCT rsShareKey) AS [Users],   
    ISNULL(ROUND(AVG(CAST(pfRating AS FLOAT)), 1), 0)  AS [Avg Page Rating] 
FROM tblReport 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN tblReportView  ON rptID = rv_rptID
     INNER JOIN tblReportShare ON rs_rptID = rptID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPageFeedback ON pfEmail = rsEmail
     INNER JOIN PMaster.dbo.tblOrganisation ON orgID = rpt_orgID
WHERE rvEmail NOT LIKE '%support%' 
    AND orgID IN (1002,1047) 
    AND rpt_qtrID IN (1) 
    AND rvPage NOT LIKE 'Arts'
GROUP BY orgID, orgName
ORDER BY orgName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably work out a way of not having to do that subquery, but to make it work, you have to add a correlation between your [Page View] subquery's orgID and the one in the main query. It is a bit hard to give you a complete example since you don't alias all your column names, but something like this on the [Page View] subquery should make it work:

```
SELECT COUNT (rvSessionKey)
FROM tblReport tt
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblReportView  ON rptID = rv_rptID
WHERE rpt_orgID IN (1002,1047)  
  AND tt.rpt_orgID = tblReport.orgID --Correlation to the outside query
  AND rvEmail NOT LIKE '%support%' 
  AND rpt_qtrID IN (1)) AS [Page View],
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the sub query altogether. `COUNT(rvSessionKey)` will give you the number of entries in the selected set for the grouped organisation. This I guess gives you the number of pages, and the `COUNT(DISTINCT rvSessionKey)`gives you the number of sessions:

```
SELECT orgID, orgName, 
    COUNT (rvSessionKey) AS [Page View],
    COUNT( DISTINCT rvSessionKey ) AS [Views], 
    COUNT(DISTINCT rsShareKey) AS [Users],   
    ISNULL(ROUND(AVG(CAST(pfRating AS FLOAT)), 1), 0)  AS [Avg Page Rating]
FROM
    .......
```

Comment: this is what i had first but it does not look at my where statement so i get a much bigger number 76 and 32 :/

Comment: @ThomasJames It does look at your where clause. The issue is that your joins are causing the rows with rvSessionKey to be duplicated in the count. You will see that 76 and 32 are 4*19 and 4*8. This means your join is combining one row from the first table with 4 rows from the second (or one to two and then to another two). You probably do need a sub query. Can you please edit the question to fully qualify the column names so we can see which columns come from which tables, e.g. `SELECT tblReport.OrgID, tblReport.orgName` etc.